Crear PDF con varias páginas con itext 7
tengo un problema que no estoy pudiendo resolver.
Tengo que generar un pdf con información y no se como crear el contenido dentro de las páginas del pdf.
Es decir, tengo un arraylist de reparticiones y a sus empleados y quiero mostrar en cada hoja una repartición con sus empleados. Pero no me doy cuenta como hacerlo.
'''
    sec = "1";

    lista = cSueldo.listarCC(sec); 
    
    sec = lista.get(0).getSecretaria(); 
    
    
    
    for(Sueldos l: lista) {
        
        empleados = cSueldo.listarEmpleadosCC(l.getCc()); 
        
        doc.add(new Paragraph(sec));
        doc.add(new Paragraph(l.getReparticion()));
        
        for(Sueldos e: empleados) {
            doc.add(new Paragraph(e.getNombre())); 
        }
        
    }

'''
Este es un código de prueba.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Buenos días Ante todo. Quiero editar la pregunta pero no me toma la edición. Mil disculpas!!
